# Change direction of trend arrow in Quicksight KPI chart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, trend, kpi

I am frequently using the KPI chart in Quicksight and particularly focusing on the displaying the trend arrow comparing the current with the status before. However, the trend arrow should not go up for some variables (e.g. costs), when the variable increases. Is there a possibility to change the direction of the arrow, for example, using the reciprocal value for the arrow but the real value for the number displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue but not using the "trend arrow" feature but the "conditional formatting" feature which offers arrows as well.